# Joining multiple columns in PySpark

Tags: python, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to join two DataFrames that have column names in common.

my DataFrames are as follows:

```
>>> sample3
DataFrame[uid1: string, count1: bigint]
>>> sample4
DataFrame[uid1: string, count1: bigint]


sample3
     uid1  count1
0  John         3
1  Paul         4
2  George       5

sample4
     uid1  count1
0  John         3
1  Paul         4
2  George       5
```

(I am using the same DataFrame with a different name on purpose)

I looked at [JIRA issue 7197 for Spark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7197) and they address how to perform this join (this is inconsistent with the PySpark documentation). However, the method they propose produces duplicate columns:

```
>>> cond = (sample3.uid1 == sample4.uid1) & (sample3.count1 == sample4.count1)
>>> sample3.join(sample4, cond)
DataFrame[uid1: string, count1: bigint, uid1: string, count1: bigint]
```

I would like to get a result where the keys do not appear twice.

I can do this with one column:

```
>>>sample3.join(sample4, 'uid1')
DataFrame[uid1: string, count1: bigint, count1: bigint]
```

However, the same syntax does not apply to this method of joining and throws an error.

I would like to get the result:

```
DataFrame[uid1: string, count1: bigint]
```

I was wondering how this would be possible

Comment: Are your values integers that you want to sum? `count1_sum = sample3_spark['count1'] + sample4_spark['count1']`?

Comment: No, I want to figure out how to perform a join. This is not an intermediate step to an end goal

Comment: Looks like it may have been [addressed in April](https://github.com/rxin/spark/commit/13e9cc92e837b9c874d2a90bec3e80bea0f66470). There might be some example syntax you can use on line 471 of python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py.

Comment: Yes, but the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: Its in line 560 of the file, but doing that produces an error.

Comment: If the documentation is in error, I'm sure the project would appreciate you telling them.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the join cond use a list of keys, in your case:

> sample3.join(sample4, ['uid1','count1'])